# How to serialize a class generated from XSD to XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd

I created an XSD file from Visual Studio and can generate a sample XML as well, but my goal is to use this XSD to create an XML file at runtime.

I used XSD.exe to generate a class from my XSD file and then created a program to populate the object from the "class". How can I serialize the object to an XML file?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731073.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have created classes to serialize and deserialize the Xml file using the XSD.exe tool you can write your instances back to files using ..

[Serialization](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-serialize-objects-to-a-file)! ([Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20130116151715/http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-serialize-objects-to-a-file))

```
  Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create);
  XmlFormatter formatter = new XmlFormatter (typeof(XmlObjectToSerialize));
  formatter.Serialize(stream, xmlObjectToSerialize);
  stream.Flush();
```

Comment: Ah, sorry, yes. I picked the binary formatter! But the XmlFormatter works too! Seen @KenF's answer.

Answer (score 9):

Both those examples leave the stream open, and XmlFormatter is part of the BizTalk libs - so XmlSerializer would be more appropriate:

```
using (Stream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));
    serializer.Serialize(stream, MyObject);
    stream.Flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Binary format is binary,   use the XML version for XML:

```
XmlFormatter serializer = new XmlFormatter(typeof(MyObject));
serializer.Serialize(stream, object1);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)?

Comment: must be System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer instead of XmlFormatter as Justin pointed out